# Helm Install from DockerHub image - DockerHub Image download fails

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, dockerhub, jupyterhub

When running the following command:

```sh
helm upgrade --cleanup-on-fail \
    -- install $releaseName $dockerHubName/$dockerHubRepo:$tag \
    -- namespace $namespace \
    -- create-namespace \
    -- values config.yaml
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to download "$dockerHubName/$dockerHubRepo"
```

I've also tried with different tags, with semantic versioning (tag="1.0.0") and there's a image with the tag "latest" on the DockerHub repo (which is Public)

This also works with the base JuPyTerHub image `jupyterhub/jupyterhub`

Comment: Usually Docker Hub holds Docker images, but `helm install` wants to install Helm charts; those are different things.  Do you have a more specific example, including your own chart, without variables, that fails?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have built a Docker Image hosted on DockerHub and am trying to get that to run as the SingleUser server image using JuPyTerHub for Kubernetes - any idea how to get JuPyTerHub for Kubernetes to use a custom Docker image instead of the default jupyterhub/jupyterhub image?

Comment: You'd need to include that as the `image:` in one of your Kubernetes manifests, in something like a `templates/deployment.yaml` file inside the Helm chart.  You can't directly `helm install` it.

Comment: You can use this solution from [JupiterHub site](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#choose-and-use-an-existing-docker-image) to use other Docker image.

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin Thanks for posting that, I found that exact site and used that in my solution. If you want, post an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on information from the [jupyterhub for kubernetes site](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#choose-and-use-an-existing-docker-image), to use a different image from jupyter/docker-stacks, the following steps are required:

> 1. Modify your config.yaml file to specify the image. For example:

```
     singleuser:
       image:
         # You should replace the "latest" tag with a fixed version from:
         # https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/tags/
         # Inspect the Dockerfile at:
         # https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/HEAD/datascience-notebook/Dockerfile
         name: jupyter/datascience-notebook
         tag: latest
```

> 2. Apply the changes by following the directions listed in [apply the changes](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/extending-jupyterhub.html#apply-config-changes).
>
> If you have configured prePuller.hook.enabled, all the nodes in your
> cluster will pull the image before the hub is upgraded to let users
> use the image. The image pulling may take several minutes to complete,
> depending on the size of the image.
>
> 3. Restart your server from JupyterHub control panel if you are already logged in.

Comment: Exactly what I did, thanks for posting mate! Hope you get heaps of fake internet points from this haha!